# What's the actual name of this lollipop like icon?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-vector-icons

I'm creating a view which will allow selecting components on the screen similar to the selectable text in react native (ios).

Can't find this lollipop like icon in `react-native-vector-icons` repo.

[image]

Comment: Just add your own with Fontello.